Why does Magneto not wear metal armor?
Magneto is the master of magnetism, capable of very precise control of metals, even to the level of building machines. Why does he not wear metal armor — either simple as a coat of plates or sophisticated with high-tech features up to an Iron-Man-level suit?
One answer may be because he relies on his magnetic force field to provide protection, but armor can also protect him from dry blows and plastic projectiles, and also works when he is not directly aware of the threat.
Note that he does wear a helmet, but its main purpose is to protect him from psychic attacks (telepathy).

Because in the comics he can generate a magnetic field around him that makes him invulnerable.

I've read somewhere that the suit is already made of metal, so it's like a super-bulletproof-chainmail. I can't find any official sources to back that up. :-(

For the same reason that (especially female) superheroes that aren't invulnerable don't wear hi-tech body armor: Comics aesthetics.

@RubioRic - You are correct. He also periodically wears specially constructed high-tech suits that allow him to duplicate other mutant's superpowers (like Havok's chest blast)

Magneto's typical armour is made of metal. If he gets blasted, he is able to reform his outfit from metals around him.

Made of flexible metal bonded on the molecular level, [Magneto's armour] provides protection against projectiles, energy weapons, and concussive force; helmet also provides protection from psionic attack
The Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe: Master Edition #7

We see him assemble his "metal mesh armored fabric" (and helmet) from raw materials on several occasions in Uncanny X-Men.


Uncanny X-Men #150



Uncanny X-Men #275



Uncanny X-Men #274

